# ¿Como puedo resolver esto de forma recursiva?

Tags: java, visual-studio, string, estructuras-de-datos, recursión

Hola Tengo un problema y es que dado una fracción simplificarlo lo que mas se puede ya lo resolvi de forma normal pero ahora no se como hacerlo de forma recursiva algun consejo o ayudaria estaria genial porque no se como resolver de esta forma
tambien la entrada y salida debe de ser en esta forma

Entrada
6/4
Salida
3/2

Entrada
24/4
Salida
6/1

Esta de forma normal ahora no se como hacerlo en forma recursiva

```
   public class SimplificarFracciones {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String textos = br.readLine();
    String[] parts = textos.split("/");
    int numerador = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int denominador = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    SimplificarFracciones reducir = new SimplificarFracciones();
    reducir.reducirFracciones(numerador, denominador);
}

public void reducirFracciones(int numerador, int denominador) {

    for (int i = 2; i <= numerador; i++) { //puede ser numerador o denominador

        int residuoNumerador = numerador % i;
        int residuoDenominador = denominador % i;
        if (residuoNumerador == 0 && residuoDenominador == 0) {

            numerador = numerador / i;
            denominador = denominador / i;

            System.out.println(numerador + "/" + denominador);
            break;

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Esta seria la forma "Recursiva" ayuda please
public class ReduccionFraccionesRecursivo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String textos = br.readLine();
    String[] parts = textos.split("/");
    int numerador = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int denominador = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    System.out.println(reducirFracciones(numerador, denominador));

}

public static String reducirFracciones(int numerador, int denominador) {

  //  if (numerador <= 2 && denominador <= 2) {
      //  return "1";
    //}
    numerador = numerador % 2;
    denominador = denominador % 2;

    if (numerador!=0 & denominador!=0) {
        return "0"; //fix
    }
    return reducirFracciones(numerador, denominador) + "/" + reducirFracciones(numerador, denominador); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class SimplificarFracciones {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String textos = br.readLine();
        String[] parts = textos.split("/");

        int numerador = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        int denominador = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

        SimplificarFracciones.reducirFracciones(numerador, denominador);
    }

    public static void reducirFracciones(int numerador, int denominador) {
        reducirFraccionesAuxiliar(numerador, denominador, 2);
    }

    public static void reducirFraccionesAuxiliar(int numerador, int denominador, int divisor) {
        int min = Math.min(numerador, denominador);

        if (divisor > min) {
            System.out.println(numerador + " / " + denominador);
            return;
        }

        if (numerador % divisor == 0 && denominador % divisor == 0) {
            reducirFraccionesAuxiliar(numerador / divisor, denominador / divisor, divisor);
            return;
        }

        reducirFraccionesAuxiliar(numerador, denominador, divisor + 1);
    }
}
```

Creas una función auxiliar que gestione el llamado incial de la función principal, luego haces los llamados recursivos correspondientes. En la primera parte revisas cuál de los elementos es el menor y sobre este haces comparaciones de ¿el divisor podrá dividir mi número menor? En caso de que no sabrás tu opareción terminó por lo tanto dejas de hacer llamados recursivos, **esta es tu condición de parada**.

Para los otros casos en donde un mismo divisor puede seguir diviendo numerador y denominador haces un llamado recursivo con el mismo divisor. En caso de que no puedan ser divididos por ese divisor llamas al siguiente valor candidato a ser divisor.

Comment: Gracias Crack!!